# Finding Ryan/Hayes/Fleming family (1850) cemetery near Drumwood, Ireland?

Tags: ireland, cemeteries

The Ryan family I'm researching on lived/born in Drumwood around 1850 and travelled to Solohead (https://registers.nli.ie/parishes/0278) for weddings and baptisms. What cemetery would they have likely used? And is there any online gravestone descriptions for that cemetery? They were Roman Catholic.

Trying to hunt down a Michael Ryan and Bridget Burke, Martin Hayes and Johanna (or Mary) Fleming, and Sir John Hayes. The family that was left behind in Ireland.

Michael, Bridget, Martin and Johanna will be born around 1815. John might be born around 1845. John and Johanna were still alive in 1875 as Martin Frances Ryan stayed with them for a few years.

I found the Solohead cemetery details but no one with those names in the right dates.
http://www.irelandgenweb.com/irltip/Records/SoloheadGraveyard.htm

[image]

My family tree for details:
https://www.ancestry.com.au/family-tree/tree/120872934/family?cfpid=201001988808

Comment: Which Sir John Hayes do you require ? Sir John Macnamara Hayes, 1st Baronet (c.1750–1809) was a military physician. Hayes was born in Limerick, Ireland. He was a British Army surgeon in the USA ... Sir John Hayes - Australian Dictionary of Biography
adb.anu.edu.au/biography/hayes-sir-john-2173 Sir John Hayes (1768-1831), naval officer and explorer, was baptized on 11 February 1768 at Bridekirk, Cumberland, England, the son of Fletcher Hayes of ...

Comment: I don't know any information about Sir John Hayes other than Martin stayed with him and Johanna in 1875. He was Martin's Uncle. It might mean that Martin Hayes was dead before 1875 since his name wasn't mentioned. 

He may be the son of Martin and Johanna Hayes but I haven't found any evidence yet to say. I could look at the people you have listed and see if they are right ones. He may have left Ireland like the Ryan family. He probably was born around 1840.

Comment: The Johns you have listed would be too old but thanks for listing.